# What is the proper way to embed the HTML of an external form such as payflowlink from paypal?

Tags: forms, embed, customization, paypal

I've had a request to paste in the following into a donations page for a group. The trouble is that WP is (rightfully) curtailing this HTML to prevent me or anyone from doing something less than honest.

```
    <form action="https://payflowlink.paypal.com" method="POST">

    <input name="LOGIN" type="hidden" value="XXXXXXXXXX" />

    <input name="PARTNER" type="hidden" value="PayPal" />

    <input name="DESCRIPTION" type="hidden" value="Donation" />

    <input name="AMOUNT" type="hidden" value="5.00" />

    <input name="TYPE" type="hidden" value="S" />

    <input type="submit" value="Donate here" />

    </form>
```

**Question:**

That said, how could I display this one-button form in a wordpress page?

**Other things I've come across**

I've evaluated other play-nice-with-paypal plugins but they are overkill for the scope of this. They would be nice to learn more about but for now, I really just want to (safely) embed this form.

- [PayPal PHP SDK Class Library](http://www.binpress.com/app/paypal-php-sdk-class-library/612)
- [Form Maker Plugin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QelKxyW7M98%E2%80%8B) (links to video how to)

**What looks promising**:

- [Simple Embed Code](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-embed-code/)

Answer (score 0):

The code you use is incomplete, but otherwise I'm not sure what you mean by WP "curtailing."

Assuming you (or someone) with admin or editor permissions is able to use the post editor, you should be able to add "unfiltered html" via the Text screen. If you (or someone) needs to enable users with lower permissions to do so, you would need to override.